# Adding Things within a Layout causes a Crash

Tags: android, xml, xamarin

So There was a layout I wanted changed. So I added a linear layout to it and somehow it crashed code that wasn't even slightly related to it. So here Ill post some code.

Here is my main file and Ill point where the crash happens.
         protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
         {

```
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layoutLogin);



        gbtnSignUp = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnSignUp);
        gbtnSignIn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnSignIn);
        gbtnSignUp.Click += gbtnSignUp_Click;
        gbtnSignIn.Click += gbtnSignIn_Click; // here is where it crashes
    }
```

Now my layout. Ill pinpoint which part I add adds the crash.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:weightSum="100"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ListView
    android:layout_weight="80"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ListViewHighlight"
    android:id="@+id/companyListView" />
<ProgressBar
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ListViewHighlight"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1" />
<LinearLayout// just from this linear layout existing it causes a crash
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
    <TextView
        android:text="Text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/textView1" />
    <ImageButton
        android:src="@drawable/defaultAdd"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="90"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This layout isnt even linked to the view that is causing the crash. Heck I've even removed all references to this view from within the project and it still crashed.

here is the error message forcing me to break at the line I specified.

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Also I can comment this line out, yet itll make it able to run but ill still be able to press the button which then does some very bizzare behaviour, which I shouldn't be able to press it to begin with.

xml of login button

```
   <Button
    android:text="Sign In"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="15"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/btnSignIn"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:background="@drawable/ButtonSignInStyle"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />
```

Comment: Nevermind now after readding the linear layout the code lets it pass. Now it breaks if I have something inside that linear layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this problem was some messed up situation that happened when I exported my program in order to move it to another folder. I copied and pasted my files to my old version in its original folder and it worked perfectly. So if anyone has moved files in a not so great way it may cause unforeseen problems that don't make sense like this one.

Answer (score 1):

Your layout does not contain buttons with the ids `btnSignUp` and `btnSignIn`. You need to add them or remove the 4 lines in your activity code.

**Missing in your layout**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSignUp" 
    .../>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSignIn" 
    .../>
```

Comment: but they do. I'll add the code for one of the buttons

Comment: Then please ask complete questions providing all information next time -.-